# How do I get Thunderbird to always show embedded images?

Tags: xubuntu, thunderbird, mail

I'm tired of clicking "Show images" for nearly every email. Is there an option or addon I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla have a page that examine this issue. One solution includes the one already given but another is to to use the Config editor to create a mail.trusteddomains setting that specifies what e-mail domains it should automatically display remote images for. 
Details can be found at the following link.

[Privacy basics - Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Privacy_basics_%28Thunderbird%29)

> Its possible to display all images from any sender, though its not
>   recommended since malware can be embedded in images, and spammers will
>   be able to verify your e-mail address. If you want to do this use the
>   Config editor to toggle the preference
>   mailnews.message_display.disable_remote_image to false. A better
>   alternative would be to use the Config editor to create a
>   mail.trusteddomains setting that specifies what e-mail domains it
>   should automatically display remote images for. This is much easier
>   than having to specify each email address, but you're taking the risk
>   that you won't get any messages with a spoofed From: header in one of
>   those domains. The setting contains a list of domains separated by
>   commas, with no wild cards, white space or subdomains allowed.

Answer (score 5):

well you can do that . open your thunderbird and then directed to Tools > Options > Advanced > and click the Config Editor button as

[image]

Then in the search box type as `mailnews.message_display.disable_remote_image` and it will list as follows

[image]

There change the value as `False` to `true`.

Then your issue will be solved.
[credit](http://usefulpc.blogspot.in/2012/06/always-show-images-in-thunderbird.html)

Comment: The value was already `true`.

Comment: I've fixed the answer, which was a little unclear. The flag is "disable_remote_image", meaning, when it's true, remote images are disabled. You need to set it to false, to show them. The name is a little unwieldy, and not entirely intuitive, but there you have it!

Answer (score 1):

Go to your menubar

> View > Message Body As: > Original Html

Make certain "Original Html" is checked. That may solve your problem provided

```
mailnews.message_display.disable_remote_image
```

is set to `true` as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

For the Thunderbird 38.8.0 I have all options mentioned above set to true however it started showing images in some emails for me only after I've done the following:

Edit > Preferences > Privacy > Mail Content  > Tick the "Allow remote content in messages"